# How much load DC motor can move?

Tags: voltage, motor, load, rpm, gear

with 1000 rpm how much load it can move on 12v?

I want to no load of DC gear motor on 12v and 5v

[image]

Comment: What force is resisting the movement?

Comment: There's no way to answer the question from the information provided.

Comment: There should also be a TORQUE specification for this motor.

Comment: Please provide details of the application where this motor is used/proposed to be used.

Comment: @jwh20 at the risk of being pedantic; you can actually tease out the stall torque from the given information. OP's question is still unanswerable, but it's useful to know that you only need the no-load speed at a given voltage, and the max current specifications of a motor to get useful information about how much torque it can produce

Answer (score 1):

This can't be answered based on the information you have provided.

It depends on what force is resisting the movement. One very strong person can pull a train, slowly. The train is very heavy, but there's nothing actually holding it back. But they couldn't pull a car with the brakes on because the brakes are on.

It also depends how strong the motor is. There should be a specified torque. We can *estimate* this based on the electrical power and the speed but it would only be an estimate.

It also depends on the gears. Because the gears change the speed and the torque.

It also depends on how you connect the motor to the thing being pulled. Because wheels are like gears. If you pull something with a rope for example, you put a cylinder on the motor and the rope winds up onto the cylinder. But a big cylinder will increase the speed and decrease the torque, and a small cylinder will decrease the speed and increase the torque. It's nothing to do with the motor, but it still affects how well you can pull the load.